# Document opened for editing - twice

Tags: document-library, word

After recently setting up a document library for my company, I uploaded a file to the library. I tried to open it in Word, however I was using Chrome browser and it didn't open (got the message Microsoft, you want me to use IE, thx). Then I switched over to IE and opened it in Word for editing. But now my name shows up twice in the "authors editing" toolbar.

[image]

I closed Chrome, Word, and IE and repeated, but I get the same behavior. I want to move the file to a different folder in the library, but it says

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> The server has encountered the following error(s):
>
> Filename.docx
>
> The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user.

... but that's me and it's not true. How can I release the file?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question, but if you need to use IE and prefer Chrome, you can use add-in called "IE Tab". Url: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en You can also use it to login to SP using 2 different users.

Comment: @tsap amazingly, this actually solved the problem. I installed the extension, opened the document with it, and I wasn't there twice anymore. Then I was able to move the file. Thanks man, write this answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: The short term check-out should release the lock after a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use IE and prefer Chrome, you can use add-in called "IE Tab". Url: [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en) You can also use it to login to SP using 2 different users.